# How do I overwrite Bootstrap SCSS variables for my django website using PyCharm?

Tags: django, sass, compilation, pycharm, frontend

I'm using **PyCharm** to manage my **django** files and for the front end I'm using **Bootstrap**. I'm currently using the **CDN** method to point to the bootstrap files in my base.html file.

I've recently come to a point where I want to customize some of the SCSS variables that bootstrap provides, but I'm puzzled and can't find a guide anywhere to how to do this with my configuration.

I used **npm** to install the bootstrap files to my outer project folder. I've tried installing `django-sass-compiler` using pip, and then adding the required setting to my settings.py, but when I ran the command "`python manage.py sass-compiler`" (as per the PyPi docs), I got "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_sass_compiler'`"

I'm assuming that if I were to get that working then it would compile my custom SCSS file into a CSS file that would overwrite my current 'main.css' (is that right?), however I can't even figure out that part.

If someone could please point me in the right direction then that would be great, there really isn't a lot of help out there for sass, pycharm, django & bootstrap together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone wondering how I fixed this**

The problem was not with bootstrap! My colours were actually overwriting the bootstrap styles, however, I could not see the changes because my browser had cached some of the information.

Going to F12 -> Network Settings -> Disable Cache fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to compile the CSS manually. You can use tools like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/).
To accomplish that in Django, You will have to:

- Create a directory named `static` at your project level directory. In `satic` add another folder called `css`. Go ahead and add the compiled CSS file.
- Change

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

to

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and add

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

- In your `base.html` file at the very top add

```
{% load static %}
```

and you can link the `base.html` file to your compiled CSS file like shown below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/mycss.css">
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try using Koala and come back to mark the answer if it works. I've not heard anybody mention Koala  . Could I just confirm that I can extend the Bootstrap SCSS with my own custom SCSS by using "@import..." (as per the Bootstrap docs), then compile that to CSS to overwrite my existing CSS file (in static)?

Would I have to remove the CDN link from my base template as well? Thanks

Comment: They can still work together.. Just import your css after the CDN CSS
```<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<!-- Your file css --> ```